# Does Kőnig's theorem hold for infinite bipartite graphs?

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs, matching-theory, infinite-graphs

[Kőnig's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C5%91nig%27s_theorem_(graph_theory)) states that in a bipartite graph the size of the maximal matching equals the size of the minimal vertex cover.

I learned it as an equivalence to Hall's theorem and we proved it using Hall's theorem. We also proved it to be equivalent to Dilworth's theorem.

Both Hall's theorem and Dilworth's theorem have counterexamples on infinite graphs/partially ordered sets. Since they are equivalent I would expect that there exists a counter example to Kőnig's theorem as well, but I didn't manage to find one.

It would make sense to me, if we go to the infinite graphs (matching $M$, vertex cover $U$) $|U| \geq |M|$ still holds. So I need to find either an infinite graph, which has both only finite and fulfills the condition above or have one infinite and the other finite or to have different infinite cardinalities.

Comment: I mean the size/cardinality of the vertex covering is greater or equal to that of the matching as I saw in it the proof.

Comment: I would like to know whether a counter example, i.e. a graph where those cardinalities aren't equal, exists. Finding an infinite graph where both are equal doesn't really help me understand whether Kőnig's theorem holds for infinite graphs.

Comment: @bof To summarize: Is there an infinite bipartite graph G that doesn't fulfill Kőnig's theorem.

Comment: @bof The above condition is stated in the text in special math characters(thanks to Rócherz): $|U| >= |M|$, since I assume that it still holds in the infinite setting, which might not be true.

Comment: @bof No. I want to know whether an infinite bipartite graph exists, that doesn't fulfills Kőnig's theorem. I conjectured based on $|U|>=|M|$ that if there would exist one, that then the vertex cover needs to be larger than the matching.

Comment: You **said** you want to find a graph which fulfills the condition $|U|\ge|M|$ but you **mean** you want a graph which fulfills the condition $|U|\gt|M|$; because a graph with $|U|\ge|M|$ is not necessarily a counterexample, but a graph with $|U|\gt|M|$ would be a counterexample. I was trying to persuade you to state your question correctly, but I give up.

Comment: Let $G$ be a graph and let $\beta$ be the minimum cardinality of a vertex cover in $G$. (1) If $\beta$ is finite and $G$ is bipartite, then $\beta$ is also the maximum cardinality of a matching in $G$, by Kőnig's theorem. (2) If $\beta$ is an infinite cardinal, then (trivially) $\beta$ is also the maximum cardinality of a matching in $G$, in fact, every maximal matching in $G$ has cardinality $\beta$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any graph $G$, not necessarily finite or bipartite, let $\beta(G)$ be the minimum size of a vertex cover of $G$.
I believe you know the following two facts:

**Theorem 1.** In any graph $G$, any matching $M$ satisfies $|M|\le\beta(G)$.

**Theorem 2.** (Kőnig) Any finite bipartite graph $G$ contains a matching $M$ such that $|M|=\beta(G)$. (In view of Theorem 1, this means that $\beta(G)$ is the *maximum* cardinality of a matching in $G$.)

Your question (as I understand it) is answered by the following observations:

**Theorem 3.** Let $G$ be any bipartite graph. If $\beta(G)$ is finite, then $G$ contains a matching $M$ such that $|M|=\beta(G)$.

**Proof.** Let $M$ be a matching in $G$ of maximum size, and assume for a contradiction that $|M|=m\lt\beta(G)$. Let $U_1,\dots,U_{2^m}$ be all of the $m$-element sets obtained by taking one endpoint of each edge in $M$. For each $i\in\{1,\dots,2^m\}$, since $|U_i|\lt\beta(G)$, we can choose an edge $e_i$ of $G$ which is not covered by $U_i$. Let $H$ be a finite subgraph of $G$ containing the edges of $M$ and the edges $e_i$. By Theorem 2, $H$ contains a matching $N$ of size $|N|=\beta(H)\gt m=|M|$, contradicting the assumption that $M$ is a maximum matching.

**Theorem 4.** Let $G$ be any graph. If $\beta(G)$ is infinite, then $G$ contains a matching $M$ such that $|M|=\beta(G)$.

**Proof.** By Zorn's lemma, $G$ contains a maximal (*) matching. Let $M$ be any maximal matching in $G$, and assume for a contradiction that $|M|=\kappa\lt\beta(G)$. Let $U$ be the set of all endpoints of edges in $M$. Since $|U|=2|M|=2\kappa\lt\beta(G)$, there is an edge $e$ of $G$ which is not covered by $U$. Then $M\cup\{e\}$ is a matching in $G$ which properly extends $M$, contradicting the assumed maximality of $M$.

**Corollary.** Any bipartite graph $G$ contains a matching $M$ with $|M|=\beta(G)$, that is, $\beta(G)$ is the maximum cardinality of a matching in $G$.

(*) A maxim**AL** matching is a matching which cannot be properly extended; not the same thing as maxim**UM** matching, which is a matching of maximum possible cardinality.